# How can I know the eventual height of a Collapsed element in C#/XAML?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, animation

I want to implement a 'blind down' animation. It goes as follows,

1. Start with element `Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed` with `Height = 0`
2. Set the element to `Visibility = Visibility.Visible`
3. Animate `Height` from 0 to the final height

However animation defined in XAML through Blend requires the final height to be known beforehand. In C# the final height can be set programatically but I don't know how to obtain the final height when it is in the Collapsed state.

How would I go about programming this effect?

I'm using Windows Phone 7.

Comment: In that case hidden should be the visibility.

Comment: What do you mean? There are two states for `Visibility` in Silverlight, `Visible` and `Collapsed` ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know that height. For the tasks like that, MS already has the feature called "fluid layout".

Take a look here:

[image]

The green checkbox toggles what is called "Fluid layout". You should turn it on.
The pink field is the default transition duration. You should set it to some reasonable value.

After you'll do that, you can start your element with Visibility.Collapsed and leave the height not-animated - the visual state manager will produce a nice transition for you. If you'll check the yellow button, you'll preview the translations in Blend as you click on different states.

[More info in this presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/CL55), play it from the 00:04:00.

Comment: This is awesome, I'll probably use this technique for this particular blind down effect. But say my animation is part of a StoryBoard with lots of other animations that need to be triggered at particular times - I will still need the Height right?

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's another technique how to animate height from 0 to 100%.

**Warning:** untested code below - a compilation from another SO answers.

In your element (here I assume it's a stack panel):

```
<StackPanel x:Name="myTransformPanel">
         <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform></ScaleTransform>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
</Stackanel>
```

In the animation:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="myTransformPanel"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
        From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```